# Extract tuple from list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

I have this list:
 [(hello(21,15),'now')]
A tuple inside a list, and I want to extract the tuple 
that way the output is

(hello(21,15,'now')

Comment: do you ve any other object apart from tuple inside the list

Comment: Nope just a tuple, what @sshashank said made sens it soled my problem ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do:

```
lst[0]
```

to get the first element since list indices start at `0`

#### Examples

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a[0]
1
>>> a[2]
3
```

#### Your case

```
>>> a = [(hello(21,15),'now')]
>>> a[0]
(hello(21,15), 'now')
```

If you further want to get the `'now'` text just do:

```
>>> a[0][1]
'now'
```

#### Extension

If you want to get a range of values from a list, you can do use `[:]` as follows:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> a[2:6]     #this gets the elements from index 2 to 5
[3,4,5,6]
>>> a[-1]      #this gets the last element of the list
8
```